# parsing a variable from class to class

Tags: c#, class, variables, parameter-passing

I would like to parse a variable example number from one class to another as show in the code below:

```
public class Gettemp // is the "public" will affect the passing of variable operation?
{
    public void temp(string temp)
    {
        temp = "123";  // things that i wanted to pass from this class 
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void STARTbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        MessageBox.Show() // i wan to show the variables here
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking. There isn't any connect between `STARTbtn_Click` and the `Gettemp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making that method return the temp value :

```
public string temp()
    {
        string temp = "123";

        return temp;  // things that i wanted to pass from this class 
    }
}

private void STARTbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Gettemp _GetTemp = new Gettemp();

        string temp = _GetTemp.temp();

        MessageBox.Show(temp);
    }
```